# jquery jcarousel error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jcarousel'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jcarousel

I know that the obvious answer to this problem would be to check if the jquery and jcarousel scripts were loaded correctly, but I can see the resources in my browser debugger, and thus think that this is not the problem. I cannot seem to get it to run the script:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<meta name="description" content="Support and Information for the Trail Tracker application" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../App_Themes/Default/skin.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            // Configuration goes here
        });
    });
```

Here is the markup that corresponds to the method call:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" Runat="Server">
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<li>yo</li>
<li>soy</li>
</ul>
```

please help; I have minimal experience with javascript.

Comment: I Think jQuery is not initialized. Check if you can make an "alert('foo');" instead of your jQuery call. This way you can figure out whether jQuery is loaded correctly.

Comment: It successfully Alerted me "foo": jquery is loaded. I see it and the jcarousel files in my debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok; the guy who actually answered the question but then deleted his answer never posted back, so here is the solution that worked:

I had loaded the jQuery library once in the .master page and once on the .aspx page. I guess they cancelled each other out *~shrug~*, because when I removed one reference, everything fell into line.

Answer (score 3):

No. Basically, your plugin is not binded to `jquery.fn.init` as it should. What you can do is this: `console.dir(jQuery.fn.init.prototype);`. This will list all the functions binded to an element. Then check you are loading the plugin properly. Basically, javascript is telling you it cannot find a method with the name `jcarousel` under the `jquery.fn.init.prototype`, which most likely implies you are not loading it properly.

Basically all you need is to load the script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "../jCarousel.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously adjust the filename/path according to what you have and you should be good to go.

Comment: How, then, can I load it properly? What am I looking for? If it is loaded properly, will it appear under the "ready" function?

Comment: As it turns out, the guy who removed his answer got it right. jquery was loaded twice: once on the master page and once in the script tag. That you for your help. **IF HE SEES THIS AND REPOSTS HIS ANSWER I WILL GIVE HIM THE CHECK!**